# Java - how to access to Excel resource without having a class in same directory?

Tags: java, resources, path

I am confused how to access to the excel file in my directory. I'm using `Netbean 6.9 + GlassFish v3 bundle`.

```
project
  |
  |----web
  |----src
        |---local.test.jaxrs
                  |
                  |-----ExcellaTestResource
                  |-----myTemplate.xls
```

Like above I figured **if the excel file is in the same directory as resource class** (i.e. ExcellaTestResource), I can get the excel file successfully.

```
URL templateFileUrl = ExcellaTestResource.class.getResource("myTemplate.xls");
```

But of course this is not good to mix java class and excel file in the same directory.

So I moved the excel file to `project/web/myTemplate.xls`

```
project
      |
      |----web
      |     |-----------myTemplate.xls //new location
      |
      |----src
            |---local.test.jaxrs
                      |
                      |-----ExcellaTestResource
                      |
```

Now I can't use the `getResource()` method because `myTemplate.xls` is not in the same directory as the Java class ExcellaTestResource :(

I could possibly provide full URL path to the m`yTemplate.xls` like though.. doesn't fell right.

```
URL location = new URL("C://User/mmm/foo/bar/project/web/myTemplate.xls")
```

So, how can I access to myTemplate.xls in new location (...web/myTemplate.xls) ?

**update**

I tried using File class but my test shows it is not looking at the directory of my intention..

```
 File myFile = new File("web/myTemplate.xls");

 System.out.println(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

**C:\Users\m-takayashiki.netbeans\6.9\config\GF3\domain1\web\myTemplate.xls**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put it in your WEB-INF/classes, you can use getResourceAsStream() from servlet context to get an InputStream.

If you have to pass a String from that InputStream to another class, then read the contents in, create a String, and pass that.  I thought your question meant that you had to be able to read the contents of an Excel file from your web app context.

Is this a web app or not?

A [file URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) looks like this: "file:///c:/User/mmm/foo/bar/project/web/myTemplate.xls"

But if you want to do this in a web app, put the Excel file in WEB-INF/classes and use the servlet context to getResourceAsStream() and read the contents using the InputStream.  Then turn those bytes into a String.

Comment: I forgot to include bit more detail about my situation..I'll add.

Comment: I've updated the post, I can't (i think) use stream as I have to pass String to the ReportBook constructor.

Comment: I thought I understood but how do I access to myTemplate.xls which is in web directory? (that was the original question, sorry for not being clear) My main purpose is to access to that excel file. Not sure if I need to streamized it or URL etc, kind of confusing in this region

Comment: You have a directory "web" - is this a web app or a desktop?

Comment: Like...  Project--web--WEB-INF--blah

Comment: Looks like I can just use File and give absolute path but still searching why relative path is set to ...domain1/..  maybe its GlassFish default that can be configured somewhere. (in that case, my question is no longer (maybe) relevant to my original..

Comment: Ohh ok your last sentence finally got in my brain! Ok I understand what you mean now. I was trying to just reach to the excel file and you were giving me the the additional step I can take which is to read the file. I got idea of how it should be processed. thank you

Comment: I was confused because WEB-INF/classes sounds like for Java class not Excel

Comment: It is for Java .class files, but it's automatically in the CLASSPATH for a web app.  So if you put an Excel or XML or .properties file in WEB-INF/classes, it's in the CLASSPATH.  Nothing to set...just the default.  Not Project-web - you have to follow the WAR packaging requierments.  So it's war-root/WEB-INF/classes.  Get it?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is `project/web` is not in your `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: hmm i've added the class path but no effect.

Comment: No, you didn't.  You only thought you did.  You don't understand how CLASSPATH works.